# vlc cannot play video files inside rar

Tags: vlc, ubuntu-gnome, archive, rar

I have a `.rar` file and it contains some video files.

When I open the rar and then try to open the video files from there directly it fires up vlc but vlc throws this error

`VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///tmp/`

However vlc works fine when I first extract it first and then open it.

Comment: This is … expected. Videos generally have bits and pieces at the start, mixed around the middle, and near the end that control bitrates, indexes, subtitles, and the like. I cannot think of a single compression client that can support this sort of use case 

Comment: @matigo i am able to play that in windows with 7zip and vlc

Comment: Comparing Windows to Linux is like comparing Ford to Subaru. Both will get you places in roughly the same way, but there are benefits to one over the other.

Answer (score 1):

Just unpack the .rar file. There is zero benefit of packing any modern video format into any compressed archive format, no matter if it's .rar, .zip or whatever. Videos are already compressed; chances are that the resulting .rar is even larger than the original file (because of management overhead like the .rar file header).

What 7zip probably does on Windows is it unpacks that file to a temporary file, runs vlc on it and then deletes that temporary file. And it does that over and over again for each time you click on the file.

So simply do it once and be done with it (and you can delete the .rar file after you unpacked it).